# Is it possible that black holes spin in discreet spin quanta?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, discrete, kerr-metric

Roy Kerr recently wrote a paper critical of the Penrose singularity theorem. One interpretation of his paper is that the singularity problem might be an artifact of the Schwarzchild metric and that a singularity would not be inevitable in a Kerr metric. Might that mean nature abhors the Schwarzchild metric, i.e., a black hole ***must*** spin to avoid a singularity? If so, consider the thought experiment of a black hole acquiring angular momentum from photons in falling one at a time. Suppose just the right amount of photons of a particular spin fall in so that the total angular momentum of the black hole is zero. At that moment, imagine what happens next is all infalling matter is evenly distributed in terms of their own spin so that the black hole will acquire a little bit of spin one way, then another, as it seems to oscillate between different angular momenta, e.g., clockwise and counterclockwise. If the Schwarzchild metric had to be avoided to prevent singularities, wouldn’t that then require the black hole to “skip over” the zero angular momentum state in its oscillation, i.e., it could not oscillate smoothly, but it must oscillate in discreet quanta that prevent it from reaching the zero angular momentum state?

Comment: *Is it possible…?* You’re asking a question about the quantum mechanics of black holes, but there isn’t an accepted theory of this. That means answers are going to be opinion-based, making the question off-topic. On general quantum-mechanical  grounds it would be surprising if the angular momentum of a black hole *wasn’t* quantized, but it isn’t clear why that discreteness would not include a zero-angular-momentum state.

Comment: The reason why it might not include a zero-angular-momentum state would be if a black hole needed to spin to avoid a singularity, as prompted by the recent Kerr article purporting to show that the Kerr metric for a spinning black hole could avoid a singularity.

Comment: The logical error in your question is in neglecting the causal order of events. In the Schwarzschild spacetime, in any valid coordinate system, everything outside happens before anything at the horizon and therefore before the singularity forms. Even if you send your differently polarized photons for eternity, no singularity will form until *all of them* are at the horizon.  In fact, this consideration alone (without your quantum idea) is a proof enough that the Schwarzschild singularity is unphysical. BTW, Karl Schwarzschild has never proposed this singularity or anything inside the horizon.

Comment: Secondly, even if you manage to add a single photon’s spin to a static black hole, the Schwarzschild singularity does not just disappear. This singularity mathematically is an infinitely thin (and infinitely long) line that stops existing the moment it forms. Adding a tiny angular momentum only makes this line a bit thicker (say, by one Planck length or time) converting it to a cylinder of the unstable inner Cauchy horizon. In other words, the Schwarzschild singularity may already be seen as an infinitely thin inner Cauchy region. So there may be no physical difference between these cases.